# Eziriz Reactor obfuscated dll not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, obfuscation, net-reactor

I using eziriz .net reactor For obfuscate dll. after publish web application I create new project and obfuscate main dll then reactor create a new folder named MyProject_Secure and copy obfuscated dll into it.
I replace this obfuscated dll with my dll on server but after this application get me HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden!!

Do I miss any special settings?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should add all the related files together. They should be appear at "additional panel" in reactor window.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled NecroBit you need to ensure you have "Full Trust" in your ASP.NET control panel. Otherwise the web application will not run.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Confuser Ex, it's open source and available in GitHub, 
it works like Charm:

https://yck1509.github.io/ConfuserEx/

Upvote if it helps